# Fetch JSON list data from api

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to fetch a list of questions from an endpoint that returns json formatted like so:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "question": "text",
    "option1": "text",
    "option2": "text",
    "option3": "text",
    "option4": "text",
    "answer": "text"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "question": "text",
    "option1": "text",
    "option2": "text",
    "option3": "text",
    "option4": "text",
    "answer": "text"
  }
]
```

Following the example [here](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/), I have a quiz class:

```
class Quiz extends Object with _$QuizSerializerMixin {
  List<Question> questions;

  Quiz(this.questions);

  factory Quiz.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$QuizFromJson(json);
}
```

and question class:

```
class Question extends Object with _$QuestionSerializerMixin {

  final String question;
  final String option1;
  final String option2;
  final String option3;
  final String option4;
  final String answer;

  Question(
      {this.question,
      this.option1,
      this.option2,
      this.option3,
      this.option4,
      this.answer});

  factory Question.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$QuestionFromJson(json);
}
```

with the function defined as:

```
Future<Quiz> fetchQuiz() async {
  final response = await http.get('json_endpoint.placeholder/questions');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Quiz.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load quiz');
  }
}
```

how do I pass this into a new instance of quiz? This may be obvious but I am finding it difficult.

I have tried declaring a variable as follows:

```
class QuizScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuizScreenState createState() => _QuizScreenState();
}

class _QuizScreenState extends State<QuizScreen> {
Question question
String option1
...

Quiz quiz = quiz(fetchQuiz());

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
question = quiz.nextQuestion;
option1 = question.option1;
...
```

`Quiz quiz = Quiz(fetchQuiz());` throws an error.

Comment: "which gives an error." please add the full error output.

Comment: Its an error from the IDE (Android Studio) "The argument type 'Future<Quiz>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Question>'"

Comment: Looks like you are trying to assign the result from `fetchQuiz()` to `List<Question> questions;` but I don't see in your question where this might happen. Perhaps that code is missing.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question to reflect how I am trying to assign it.

Comment: The code above doesn't include the change I suggested in my answer. It's also not clear what method contains `Quiz quiz = quiz(fetchQuiz());` and also not what `quiz(...)` is or does.

Comment: I initially declared and created `Quiz quiz = Quiz([Question(), Question()]);` to use locally and then wanted to instead be able to retrieve this from an api. quiz is supposed to be an instance of the Quiz that holds the data retrieved

Comment: Then I still think my answer should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should look like

```
Future foo() async {
  Quiz quiz = await fetchQuiz();
}
```

`fetchQuiz()` returns a `Future<Quiz>` and to get the value out, you use `await`, for that the function that contains the code (`foo()` in my example) needs to be made `async`.

Comment: I am trying to create a new object that would hold the data retrieved, which I then use to populate some Text Widgets created later.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). It lets you build UI when the `Future` completes. The result will be in `snapshot.data` if `snapshot.hasData == true`.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<Quiz>(
      future: fetchQuiz(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return _buildQuiz(context, snapshot.data);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    ));
  }

void _buildQuiz(BuildContext context, Quiz quiz) {

}
```